# Git: Merge result subset of merged file

Tags: git, git-merge

Assuming there is a `fileA` on `master` (say it consists of 1000 lines)

We are on `feature_branch`, where `fileA` has length of say 1050 lines.

Then how it it possible, being on `master` and performing

```
git merge feature_branch
```

that `fileA` ends up having (again) 1000 lines?

The merge messages showed no conflicts and informed me of

> auto merging of fileA

**update**: for what it matters:

when testing this with a new dummy project that contains **only** the specific file, then,

starting with `master`/1000 lines and

merging `feature_branch`/1050 lines into it,

**does** end up with 1050 lines.

I guess it is an issue of how the main project' history then?

Comment: Are those 1000 lines actually the same than the ones of the previous file version on each branch ? What would `git diff master^1 master` and `git diff master^2 master` give ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

This could be completely normal.  For instance, perhaps the base version also has 1050 lines, and one of the changes is to *delete* 50 lines.  Combining "delete 50 lines" with "change something else, or change nothing at all" results in "delete 50 lines" as the final change to make to that file.

#### What to know before you merge

There are several things to remember about merging in Git.  First and foremost is that Git uses merge as a verb, *to merge*, which means *to combine changes*, and that Git also uses merge as an adjective or noun, *a merge commit* or simply *a merge*, which refers to a commit that has at least two *parent* commits.

Another is that `git merge` does not always actually merge.  It can do something it calls *fast-forwarding* instead.  In this case, Git does not do the verb form at all—there's no *to merge* happening here—and does not make a merge commit.  So be sure that your merge is a real merge, which I describe below, and not one of these fast-forward non-merges instead.

Remember also that Git stores snapshots: each commit is a complete copy of *every* source file.  This factors into how the verb form, *to merge*, works.

#### "To merge" does not mean "to copy"

Merge-as-a-verb is the act of *combining changes since some common point*.  To think about this, think about two people who make two different changes: Alice fixes line 12 where the word "misspelled" is misspelled, and Bob fixes line 20 where the sentence has a wrong word.  Alice commits her spelling fix, and Bob commits his wrong-word fix.

When Alice goes to merge Bob's fix, or vice versa, Git *must not take away* the other fix.  So merging these two changes to file `README.txt` must compare Alice's version to a *merge base* version, and then compare Bob's version to *the same* merge base version.  Whatever changes Alice made go into a *changeset:* the list of "what Alice changed."  Whatever changes Bob made go into a separate changeset: what Bob changed.

Git then *combines* the two changesets, applying *both* sets of changes to the base file, to get the final result.  If Alice and Bob made their changes on different lines—as in this example—Git just takes both sets of changes.  If they changed the *same* lines, Git will look to see if they made the same *change* to those lines, and if so, take one copy of that change.  Otherwise (they changed the same lines, but in different ways) Git declares a merge conflict, leaving *you* to fix up the mess.

#### When the merge result surprises you, check out your assumptions

The first thing to do is to be sure you got a real merge.  If so, the next is to figure out what the *common base version* was.  You can do this by using the `git merge-base` command:

```
git merge-base --all a1fc931 4056ca3
```

for instance, if the two commit hashes you were merging were `a1fc931` and `4056ca3`.  To find the commit hashes, you can look at `git log --graph --oneline`; or, if the merge is finished, you can use the special Git syntax to work with the parents of the merge you just made:

```
git merge-base --all HEAD^1 HEAD^2
```

If the merge has stopped with a merge conflict, you can find the merge bases this way:

```
git merge-base --all HEAD MERGE_HEAD
```

since `MERGE_HEAD` will record the other commit's hash.

Having found the merge base—this will be some big ugly hash ID—you can now produce the two changesets that Git sees:

```
git diff --find-renames <base> <left>
git diff --find-renames <base> <right>
```

The `<base>` here is the merge base hash ID that `git merge-base --all` found.  (If it found more than one, you're in a special case that gets more difficult; with any luck, it only printed one hash ID.)  The `<left>` part is either `HEAD^1` or `HEAD`, depending on whether the merge finished: it's the commit you were on when you started the merge.  The `<right>` part is the other commit, which is either `HEAD^2` or `MERGE_HEAD`.

The output of the two `git diff`s is *what you changed* (on the left) and *what they changed* (on the right).  Git is combining those changes, or has combined them, to produce the merge that is failing or has succeeded.

#### A few more words (and a diagram) about merge bases and fast-forwarding

The act of finding a merge base, in Git, consists of scanning through the *commit graph*—or as much of it as needed—to find the *lowest common ancestor* of the two commits being merged.  If we draw the graph with earlier commits on the left, and later commits on the right, like this:

```
          o--o--L   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--o--R   <-- otherbranch
```

where each round `o` represents a commit, then the *merge base* is the first commit at which the two branches join up in the past: commit `*`, in this case.  So Git will compare commit `*` to commit `L`, and compare `*` to commit `R`, to figure out what you changed, and what they changed.

Fast-forwarding occurs when the branch sequence looks more like this:

```
...--o--*   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
         \
          o--o--R   <-- otherbranch
```

Here, the merge base commit *is* your current (HEAD) commit.  If Git were to compare commit `*` to commit `*`, what would have changed?

In this case, then, Git does not have to do any actual merging.  It can just check out commit `R` directly, because combining "nothing changed" with "whatever changed between `*` and `R`" just gives you commit `R` again.  So Git does that by default, resulting in:

```
...--o--o
         \
          o--o--R   <-- yourbranch (HEAD), otherbranch
```

and you just get their version of every file.

You can force Git to do a real merge, and make a real merge commit, resulting in this instead:

```
...--o--*---------M   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
         \       /
          o--o--R   <-- otherbranch
```

where `M` is a merge commit (merge as an adjective).  The *snapshot* stored in commit `M` will exactly match the snapshot in commit `R`, though.  Git combines your "no change at all" with their changes, applies those to the base `*`, and builds a new commit that matches `R`.